# The react app is returning/printing data for one text input but not for other. I have used the exact same blocks of code but nothing seems to work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

```
import React from 'react'


export default class Login extends React.Component {

handleSubmit=(e)=>
{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('you clikked submit')
 }    

state={
    fName:'',
    lName:'',
    gender:'',
  }
```

These are the functions i am talking about
i am using setState to set the values input from the textfield.

```
fnameChange = (e) =>{
this.setState({fName:e.target.value})
}

lnameChange = (e) =>{
this.setState({lName:e.target.value})
}



render() { 
    return (
    <div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form 
    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
    className='add-form' autoComplete="off">
        
        <div className='form-control' >
```

These are the input fields from where i am calling the functions.
both are coded in exact same way.
I am using  tags for printing  the data to  webpage.
I also tried console logging => onChange, the lastName textfield.

But some how onChange set for lastName textfield is getting fired when i enter value in firstName textfield.

```
       <div>
            <label >First Name</label>
            <input type='text' name='firstName' onChange={this.fnameChange.bind(this)} required maxLength={10}/>
            <h1>{this.state.fName}</h1>
            </div>  
            <div>
            <label >Last Name</label>
            <input type='text' name='lastName' onChanege={this.lnameChange.bind(this)} required maxLength={10}/>
            <h1>{this.state.lName}</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label >Email</label>
            <input type='text' name='email' required />
            <h1>{this.state.fName}</h1>
            </div>  
        </div>
        
        
        <div className='form-control form-control-check'>
            <p><label>Male</label>
            <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' required/></p>
            
            <p><label>Female</label>
            <input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'/></p>

            <p><label>Other</label>
            <input type='radio' name='gender' value='other'/></p>
            
        </div>
        <div className='form-control'>
        <input type='submit' value='Login'
        className='btn btn-block'
        />
        </div>   

    </form>
</div>
    )    
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems.

1. You are resetting your state on each onChange.
   You had to consider the previous values and override the state like,

   fnameChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({...this.state, fName: e.target.value });
   };

   lnameChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({...this.state, lName: e.target.value });
   };
2. You don't need to bind as you are using arrow functions.
3. You can use the value of state to make your inputs a controlled component.

   Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dufrzd?file=Hello.tsx

Comment: And yes like in the 1st answer, your `onChange` spelling is wrong in the question. But, I guess it's correct in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<input type='text' name='lastName' onChanege={this.lnameChange.bind(this)} required maxLength={10}/>
```

`onChanege` should be `onChange`